# Hibernate JPA @OneToOne Lazy loading

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading, one-to-one

I am trying to make `@OneToOne` association `LAZY`, which is `EAGER` by default.

I can think of two reasons:
1) Fake `@OneToOne` as `@ManyToOne`.
2) Have the foreign key column in owner table and then use fetch type as `LAZY`.

Can anyone please point out the pros/cons of the above strategies. Also, let me know if there is other better solution available.

Comment: Option 2 is the standard way for doing these things in JPA. I don't fully understand why you would consider option1?

Comment: Using `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` to enable lazy loading will only work if you enable weaving, either static (compile time) or dynamic (at runtime). Weaving will modify the code to have the `One` reference be "weak".

Comment: @mwhs- But, i didn't enable weaving and still it(@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)) worked.

Comment: @steelshark- I considered option1 only because for Option 2), foreign key column should be in owner table to make LAZY work. What if i can't change database schema.

Answer (score 0):

More correct and clean solution is option 2 - you do not want to modify your model only to instruct underlying ORM framework how to load your data, unless absolutely necessary. However, there are situations where this does not work out of the box, and you must either tweak JPA to really turn on LAZY behavior, or go with option 1 (however, option 1 should use `@OneToMany` instead of `@ManyToOne`).

I will explain and try to demystify option 2 - ie. LAZY loading of `@OneToOne` and `@ManyToOne`, which map reference to a single entity (not a collection). Example:

@Entity
public class Main {
  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Secondary secondary;
}

The way, how hibernate does the lazy loading, is that it creates a **[proxy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-proxies)** object with the same methods as class `Secondary`, but only with `@Id` field set and all other data fields empty. When you call any method on this object for the first time, data is loaded into a new `Secondary` object and the method call is forwarded. Difference to EAGER loading is not only that data is loaded later only when needed, but also that there will always be an intermediary object between `Main` and `Secondary` entities, even after data is loaded. This can only be done by JPA if a subclass of `Secondary` can be created (if is not final).

Another way to achieve LAZY loading is to modify the original `Secondary` class to inject data loading code into each method, so that it does not need to be proxied. In fact, the functionality of a proxy object is merged into the code of original class. This is called **weaving** (or bytecode instrumentation), and can be done during compilation or even during runtime via a special classloader or attached java agent. When comparing efficiency of execution, following inequality applies: Proxying is slower than Dynamic weaving is slower than static weaving. Therefore waving is sort of optimisation. Though, in real world, you rarely care as the slowdown is insignificant.

Generally, if you inject `EntityManager` as a Java EE resource, via `@PersistenceContext` annotation, JPA does all the proxying/weaving for you, therefore LAZY loading always works. However, if you create EntityManager manually, like `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory('unit').createEntityManager()`, then you might need to enable weaving.